# Running Multiple spiders in scrapy for 1 website in parallel?

Tags: python, web-scraping, web-crawler, scrapy

I want to crawl a website with 2 parts and my script is not as fast as I need.

Is it possible to launch 2 spiders, one for scraping the first part and the second one for the second part?

I tried to have 2 different classes, and run them

```
scrapy crawl firstSpider
scrapy crawl secondSpider
```

but i think that it is not smart.

I read the [documentation of scrapyd](http://scrapyd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html) but I don't know if it's good for my case.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is something like this:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

class MySpider1(scrapy.Spider):
    # Your first spider definition
    ...

class MySpider2(scrapy.Spider):
    # Your second spider definition
    ...

process = CrawlerProcess()
process.crawl(MySpider1)
process.crawl(MySpider2)
process.start() # the script will block here until all crawling jobs are finished
```

You can read more at: [running-multiple-spiders-in-the-same-process](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/practices.html#running-multiple-spiders-in-the-same-process).

Comment: What if say I have 300 spiders which need to run. Can this implementation hold ?

Comment: Can we also store the results separately??

Comment: This solution will not run all spider parallelly. Spiders will be run one by one from last to first.

Comment: @ScottStafford How will you run the shell?

Answer (score 7):

Or you can run with like this, you need to save this code at the same directory with scrapy.cfg (My scrapy version is 1.3.3) :

```
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

setting = get_project_settings()
process = CrawlerProcess(setting)

for spider_name in process.spiders.list():
    print ("Running spider %s" % (spider_name))
    process.crawl(spider_name,query="dvh") #query dvh is custom argument used in your scrapy

process.start()
```

Answer (score 3):

Better solution is (if you have multiple spiders) it dynamically get spiders and run them.

```
from scrapy import spiderloader
from scrapy.utils import project
from twisted.internet.defer import inlineCallbacks


@inlineCallbacks
def crawl():
    settings = project.get_project_settings()
    spider_loader = spiderloader.SpiderLoader.from_settings(settings)
    spiders = spider_loader.list()
    classes = [spider_loader.load(name) for name in spiders]
    for my_spider in classes:
        yield runner.crawl(my_spider)
    reactor.stop()

crawl()
reactor.run()
```

**(Second Solution):**
Because `spiders.list()` is deprecated in Scrapy 1.4 Yuda solution should be converted to something like

```
from scrapy import spiderloader    
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

settings = get_project_settings()
process = CrawlerProcess(settings)
spider_loader = spiderloader.SpiderLoader.from_settings(settings)

for spider_name in spider_loader.list():
    print("Running spider %s" % (spider_name))
    process.crawl(spider_name)
process.start()
```

Comment: Will either of these solutions run all spiders concurrently?