# Speed up scrapy spiders initialisation time

Tags: scrapy, scrapyd

I have multiple Scrapy spiders that I need to run at the same time every 5 minutes. The issue is that they take almost 30 sec to 1 minute to start.

It's seem that they all start their own twisted engine, and so it take a lot of time.

I've look into different ways to run multiple spiders at the same time (see [Running Multiple spiders in scrapy for 1 website in parallel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39365131/running-multiple-spiders-in-scrapy-for-1-website-in-parallel)), but I need to have a log for each spider and a process per spider to integrate well with Airflow.

I've look into scrapyd, but it doesn't seem to share a twisted engine for multiple spiders, is that correct ?

Are they different ways I could achieve my goals ?

Comment: `they take almost 30 sec to 1 minute to start.` ??? :P are you running Scrapy on a potato?

Comment: I have around 10 spiders on a (4 vCPUs - Intel Sandy Bridge, 4.75 GB memory) machine. Is that too low?

Comment: Yup, I have never had a scraper taking so much time to start

Comment: There was some python module that was loading a big file, so I removed it, and now it's 10sec faster. However, it's still takes 20/30sec from the moment of CMD to the first output of the script...

So, is there anyway to share a twisted engine for multiple spiders?

Comment: Note that when I launch only one spider, I take 5~6s to load. The 20~30 sec are when the 10 spiders start at the same time.

Comment: we done this by writing a gateway, the gateway command scrapyd to run spiders, it sends requests concurrently