# How to make multiple Scrapy Spiders periodic and dynamic?

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

I have some Scrapy spiders which can crawl news from some newspapers. But currently I run them manually using this command -

```
scrapy crawl SpiderName
```

I am crawling news from 20 different news papers. I have 20 different spider classes to get this job done. So I have to run this command for 20 times when  I want to crawl the latest news. I want it to be automatic. I want to write a script which can continuously crawl all these newspapers after a definite period of time. I have tried to do this using a infinite while loop. But this didn't work well. Is there any other standard way to do this?

Comment: You need to schedule your spiders in some server

Comment: How to do this? Please elaborate.

Comment: Heroku has a scheduler adon which you can use to make cron jobs https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scheduler

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Running Multiple spiders in scrapy for 1 website in parallel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39365131/running-multiple-spiders-in-scrapy-for-1-website-in-parallel)

Comment: why not just use cron jobs, it's easiest way

Comment: See https://github.com/scrapy/scrapyd

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with `scrapy-do`

1.install

```
pip install scrapy-do
```

2.schedule

```
  scrapy-do-cl schedule-job --project quotesbot \
        --spider toscrape-css --when 'every 5 to 15 minutes'
```

Comment: I don't understand the schedule part. Where to run this command? Inside the spider folder? Does it crawl all the newspapers at a time? How to modify this command?